# Using multiple instances of popover with dynamicPopover template

Tags: angularjs, popover

I'm trying to use popover for multiple instances using one controller and directive. The problem I'm running into is trying define an isolated scope for use in managing the content and state of the popover.

The issue is, I click to open the popover for 'My Content 01' and both popovers are opening up and both show the content from the second popover (My Content 02). Trying to get both to use their own scope and not the shared scope.

Here's my html markup:

```
<a class="helpful-tip"
    data-my-popover
    data-popover-label=""
    data-uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl"
    data-content="<p>My Content 01</p>"
    data-popover-is-open="popoverState"
    data-popover-trigger="outsideClick"
    data-popover-placement="bottom">

<a class="helpful-tip"
    data-my-popover
    data-popover-label=""
    data-uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl"
    data-content="<p>My Content 02</p>"
    data-popover-is-open="popoverState"
    data-popover-trigger="outsideClick"
    data-popover-placement="bottom">
```

Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('project.components.common.directives.myPopover', [
    'ui.bootstrap'
])
.controller('myPopoverCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.dynamicPopover = {
        template: '<button type='button'
            id='close'
            class='close'
            data-ng-show="true"
            data-ng-click='tt_popoverState=false'>&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;</button><br>
<span data-ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></span>'
    };
})
.directive('myPopover', function ($sce, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span>{{ label }}</span>',
        transclude: true,
        controller: 'myPopoverCtrl',
        link       : function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            $scope.popoverState = false;
            $scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
            $scope.htmlContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(attrs.content);
            element.append(transclude());
            console.log(attrs);
        }
    };
});
```

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ -> Popover

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/popover